# Replacing A Word in a website?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

Hi there i am curently using greasemonkey and i have created some basic button that has diffrent functions. This time i decided to do something else and that is to replace a certain text in a website to something else. I have some images showing you what what i would like to change.

Div: http://prntscr.com/a3skwz

Text To Replace: http://prntscr.com/a3sl5b

Button style: http://prntscr.com/a3sldq

Code: http://prntscr.com/a3slq1

```
var input=document.createElement("input");
input.type="button";
input.value="Change";
input.onclick = buttononclick;
input.setAttribute("style", "font-size:18px;position:absolute;top:300px;right:170px;");
document.body.appendChild(input); 



function buttononclick()
{


}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: well i cant find any code on how i would actually replace the text STARTSIDA to Magic. Ass you can see down bellow function i dont have any code that will replace it

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you want to change the text in the div with class `h1` when you click the button. If this is the case, you can just have:

```
 function buttononclick(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('h1')[0].innerHTML = "Changed";
 }
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, could you describe what the [0] is supposed to do. I am kind of new to java scripting. If its to much information to explain, do you then have a link to a website or a video. Thanks for the help btw

Comment: Is it possible to change the color to blue ?

Comment: In case you're still wondering about the [0], when you get the elements by class name, it gets put into an array of elements with that class name. In your case, because there was only one element, the [0] means the 1st element in the array, which was the header.